# Loading design time data from file into Blend in code in WinRT

Tags: async-await, blend, design-time-data

[image: VS new project screenshot]

If you create an out-of-the-box WinRT phone app in Visual Studio, e.g. a Hub App (Windows 8.1 Universal), the resulting XAML loads design time data in XAML like this:

```xaml
<HubSection 
    IsHeaderInteractive="True" 
    DataContext="{Binding Section3Items}" 
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[3], Source={d:DesignData Source=../HubApp1.Shared/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
    x:Uid="Section3Header"
    Header="Section 3"
    Padding="40,40,40,32">
```

This design time data parsed in from a JSON file is visible in Blend:

[image: Blend screenshot]

I want to move the JSON file loading and parsing out of XAML and into C#, and have it still available in Blend. How do I do that? The challenge I face is that to be available in Blend I think the C# has to use a parameterless constructor. But loading a file (in WinRT) is asynchronous. Hence the method that opens the file must either be marked `async` and use `await`, or use a `ContinueWith` continuation. However `async` and thus `await` are not allowed in constructors and anything in a continuation appears to happen after the page loads into Blend and is not reflected in the Blend design view.

How do I load design time data, parsed from file, into Blend in code in WinRT?

(N.B. This is a generalisation of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30729999/575530).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always block the thread waiting for the task to finish using task.Wait() or task.Result (if you need the result).